# stuck in an endless refresh loop with location.replace()

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have a simple javascript code for redirecting a page on button click. Somehow when the page redirects it gets stuck in an endless page refresh loop. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Replace document</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    location.replace("https://mypage.com/admin/");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe from missing the semi colon here: location.replace("https://mypage.com/admin/"); I tried it and it seemed to work fine with it.

Comment: @Seanland thanks for pointing that out. I forgot to add that here but my original code actually has it with the same problem

Comment: maybe it is environmental? Clear your cache try a different website? Are you doing it locally or on a third party server?

Comment: The code seems fine. You can try inspecting your network tab and see where the loop is happening (it might on that /admin page)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you try putting the `<script>` above the `<button>`?

Comment: @Seanland I'm using a 3rd party server. Could that be the issue? It seems to work fine with other websites

Comment: I can't resolve that URL https://mypage.com/admin/ - I thought that was just a dummy URL. I imagine the site is the issue.

Comment: What's wrong with a plain old link? `<a href="https://mypage.com/admin/">Replace Document</a>`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. A few changes i made based on @onwsk8r's answer seemed to have solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Missing semicolon won't matter, JS doesn't care
- Cache could be a problem, but unlikely. Go to /admin and hit CTRL/CMD+SHIFT+F5 to clear yours for that url.
- Moving the script tag won't make a difference. The browser has parsed the entire document before it shows you anything.

It's a best practice to use `window.location.replace()` instead of `location.replace()`. You can simplify your code by writing `<button onclick="window.location.replace('https://mypage.com/admin')">Replace</button>`, or even better `...replace('/admin')` if the https and domain name are the same.

What happens when you go to https://mypage.com/admin/ in your browser? I'd bet that's the problem because `location.replace` is, quite literally, replacing the location in your address bar :) Change that url in your function to "https://google.com" and see if that works.

I'm putting my money on

- HTTPS is getting redirected some jacked up way on the server
- /admin is redirecting based on some missing header/cookie/etc
- Something is wrong with /admin

If it's a redirect thing, in most browsers, you'll see an error about "too many redirects".

PS- Kudos on being into ML! We are a rare breed :)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I changed location.replace() to window.location.replace and put a '/' in front of the url as ( "/https://mypage.com/admin/") as the folder for the https lies in the same root folder as the domain and that solved my problem. I am not sure why the first method didn't work because it worked for other websites   oh...and thanks for the encouragement on ML :)